# Does eas local build require `expo publish` first?

Tags: expo, eas

At present we're migrating our build infrastructure from expo with turtle to use EAS local builds.  One of the issues we had with turtle is the need for setting up an external web host or use `expo publish` before you run `turtle`.

Does EAS local build still require the `expo publish`? step before calling the `eas build --local`?

Comment: you do not need to run `expo publish` first, no. in fact it will have no effect to the build that you create afterwards.

Comment: thanks why not put that as the answer?